# Can apps use different Twitter accounts on iOS?

Tags: ios, accounts, twitter

Now that iOS has Twitter integration, and many apps use these credentials rather than asking you for the Username and Password, I was wondering if there was any way to tell each app which account to use.

For example, in **Settings > Twitter**, you can sign on to multiple accounts. Now let's say I use 2 apps that both have Twitter integration. Is there any way App A could use one account on Twitter and App B could use my other account?

Furthermore, I notice that at the bottom of the Twitter settings page, it shows a list of apps that have access to Twitter. Is there any way to allow each application access to only a specific Twitter account?

I noticed that the Twitter app itself has a

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Developers access your Twitter accounts through the [Accounts framework](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/Accounts/Reference/AccountsFrameworkRef/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011024).

When an app requests access to your accounts, it uses the `requestAccessToAccountsWithType:withCompletionHandler:` method. (The only supported account type is currently `ACAccountTypeIdentifierTwitter`.) This grants access to all accounts of that type.

Therefore, unfortunately, apps can't request access to only a single account — you have to give access to **all** of your Twitter accounts.

Comment: And which one of them will they end up using?

Comment: Whichever they choose. The app can request "`accountsWithAccountType:`" which gives them a list of all your Twitter accounts. Usually they'll present you with a list of your accounts to choose which one you want to use.